# How to defer scripts in Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

I am currently working on a Gatsby site and trying to figure out how I can defer my js scripts so that they can interact with the DOM once it's loaded. Ive tried putting them at the bottom of the body in my html.js file but they are still being loaded pre dom paint. I also tried adding `defer` to the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue for the time being by using React Helmet and adding a defer attribute to the script tag.